# MS Graph reports CSV site usage capped to 100 items?

Tags: csv, report, microsoft-graph-api

Last week I was using the graph API to build a report of SharePoint site usage using this URI:
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(period='D30')"

*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getsharepointsiteusagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http*

It was returning a csv file that contained a list of all sites (900+) which was great.

Running it this week however, I've noticed it is only coming back with 100 results. (I have tried increasing the period from D30 to D180 and this does not affect the number of results).

Just wondering if I'm doing something wrong here or if the csv report has been capped to 100 sites very recently. If it is capped - is there a way to batch request the rest of the sites? Also possible I just missed something in the documentation...

I understand that the csv might be getting generated by a service or mechanism outside of graph, but not sure where to check for that..

Answer (score 0):

Well found the source of my issue. Data in this report is sourced from the Office 365 usage reports page.

Currently - Microsoft have an advisory up regarding a service degradation of Office 365 reports where funly enough.. "Admins may only be able to view the first 100 rows of Microsoft 365 usage reports."

I expect my csv report will likely return to containing all results once Microsoft sort out this issue.